# No sound through hdmi to TV

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, hdmi

I have a Toshiba Satellite Laptop Model P745-S4102 with  Intel integrated graphics and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed recently. When I connect my HDMI TV to it I only get video through it and no audio. In the **System Settings** -> **Sound**, there is no option to select HDMI as the output. I read other threads in this site and it seems like at least guys had HDMI option but no sound. I don't even get that.

Please help!!

Comment: Sometimes I have to reboot for it to show up. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: @Nathan Dyer I tried rebooting but didn't help.

Comment: Stuart's instructions about installing the proprietary graphics driver also helped me while using Ubuntu 13.10 through an HDMI TV port. This is the simplest Ubuntu HDMI sound solution across the web--very little installation is required!

Answer (score 4):

> **TL;DR:** In short, some sound devices seem to have multiple profiles and each of these profiles might expose different outputs to the Ubuntu sound settings dialog; but they can be switched by the PulseAudio Volume Control GUI.

Install `pavucontrol`, run it via the GUI or a CLI, and switch to the configuration tab where you'll see dropdowns for every output containing their respective sound card profiles.

In our case, one of them was HDMI; and now on the sound settings configuration dialog, the option for HDMI output appears.

> **Source:** My girlfriend had come across this issue on her first day of using Ubuntu on her HP laptop. The solution for her was to follow Charlie Schams's suggestion at https://askubuntu.com/a/234784/69183.

Comment: I only see 2 options, _HMDI_ and _None_, and none of them work.

Answer (score 3):

Simple.

1. right click on speaker icon(top right, next to clock or power icon)
2. click 'sound settings'
3. on 'Output' tab, select 'HDMI/Display port'

Answer (score 0):

My GF got ASUS X55A and had same problem. Just Video, no Audio from HDMI port. I solved it in two steps:

**First step:**

uninstall driver in *"add/remove programs"* software for audio drivers called *"Via..."* and then I installed Realteck audio soft for audio driversYou can comfortly identificate your sound driver by:

1. go into the *"device manager"*
2. then go into the *"properties"* of the driver...
3. click on the tab *"specifics"* and here change *"description of the device"* into the
   *"identification of the hardware"*
4. copy there the first title (it must look like this "HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_8086&DEV_2806&SUBSYS_80860101&REV_1000)...
5. paste it into the web browser and some pages will tell you what is it and what driver is for this device. (my recommendation is realtek for audio drivers) (and also u can easiely identify every device and driver for them thru this procedure.

that was first step... if you got realtek soft installed, first step is not needed.

**Second step:**
is reinstall one of the *"Sound, game and video controllers"* and its called (I translated it from my language of windows) *" Intel (R) Voice for dysplays"*

1. go to *"properties"*
2. go to tab *"driver"*
3. click on *"backup changes of the driver"*
4. and then *"actualize driver"*

At the end try to connect HDMI and test it if it is working. GL HF ;oD

Comment: This is "AskUbuntu", not "AskWindows"

Answer (score 0):

Had a big D'oh! moment here. Might also help the eternally confused. No Linux was working for me.

Found my pc had two hdmi outputs. One on the m'board and the other on the graphics card. Linux was correctly displaying from the graphics card to the TV but failed to set audio similarly.

ROSA linux using KDE, found "HDMI2" on the audio output setup. It tested ok.
Not plain sailing from there. Programs that use the sound must be run. Go to the audio icon. At the output app, right click to find "move". Change output to hdmi2 (in my case). Or it will still play through its previously chosen port.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In 16.04 Eliah Kagan's install instructions lacked one step.
After selecting [Hardware] in [System Settings]
You need to select [Software and Updates]
Then, the [Additional Drivers] tab in the Software and Updates window 
What I saw displayed is:
Unknown: Unknown
This device is using an alternative driver
[It might be useful to note which driver and source is being used]
Select "Do not use this device"

Answer (score -1):

I've just solved my own problem after reading through all other threads like you stated.

I right clicked on the bottom right speaker icon, clicked playback devices and when the window popped up I right clicked in a blank space under the speaker device and selected *Show all disabled devices* and then enable the devices I wanted to use.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? An anonymous user has pointed out (in a suggested edit) that these seem like Windows instructions.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into exactly the same problem and followed one of the threads to install the proprietary graphics driver. Then the HDMI option appear in the hardware sound setting window. It finally worked.

To install the proprietary graphics driver:

- Click the system settings icon on your desktop.
- Click *Additional Drivers* under *Hardware*.
- Activate the driver.
- Restart your system.
- You should see the HDMI option appears in the sound window. Click to select the option.

Since I did this, I hear the audio coming out of my TV.

Comment: Santosh is using integrated intel graphics. Therefore you don't have to install proprietary drivers.